# Connection reset by peer in PHP Socket Server

Tags: php, android, sockets, server

I am trying write a PHP Socket Server for messenger. This is my PHP code:

```
if (($sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP)) === false) {
    echo "socket_create() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error()) . "\n";
}

if (socket_bind($sock, $address, $port) === false) {
    echo "socket_bind() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock)) . "\n";
}

if (socket_listen($sock, 100) === false) {
    echo "socket_listen() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock)) . "\n";
}

//clients array
$clients = array();

do {
    $read = array();
    $read[] = $sock;

    $read = array_merge($read, $clients);

    // Set up a blocking call to socket_select
    if (@socket_select($read, $write = NULL, $except = NULL, $tv_sec = 100) < 1) {
        //    SocketServer::debug("Problem blocking socket_select?");
        continue;
    }

    // Handle new Connections
    if (in_array($sock, $read)) {

        if (($msgsock = socket_accept($sock)) === false) {
            echo "socket_accept() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock)) . "\n";
            break;
        }
        $clients[] = $msgsock;
        $key = array_keys($clients, $msgsock);
        /* Enviar instrucciones. */
        $msg = "\nWelcome to the PHP Test Server. \n" .
            "Client key number: {$key[0]}\n" .
            "To quit, type 'quit'. To shut down the server type 'shutdown'.\n";
        socket_write($msgsock, $msg, strlen($msg));

    }

    // Handle Input
    foreach ($clients as $key => $client) { // for each client
        if (in_array($client, $read)) {
            if (false === ($buf = socket_read($client, 4096, PHP_NORMAL_READ))) {
                echo "socket_read() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($client)) . "\n";
                break 2;
            }
            if (!$buf = trim($buf)) {
                continue;
            }
            if ($buf == 'quit') {
                unset($clients[$key]);
                socket_close($client);
                break;
            }
            if ($buf == 'shutdown') {
                socket_close($client);
                break 2;
            }
            $talkback = "Client {$key}: Said: '$buf'.\n";
            socket_write($client, $talkback, strlen($talkback));
            echo "$buf\n";
        }

    }
} while (true);
```

When I connected via Terminal it works great. But when tried via Android connection refused. And shows me error: `socket_read() failed: reason: Connection reset by peer`. 
This is my Android code:

```
InetAddress serverAddr;
try {
    serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(dstAddress);
} catch (UnknownHostException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
try {
    socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);
    socket.setSendBufferSize(10000);
    commThread.setClientSocket(socket);

    cmThread = new Thread(commThread);
    connected = true;
} catch (Exception e) {
    connected = false;
}
```

What I must to do to solve this problem. 
Thank you!

Comment: where is your android code?

Comment: So the server is trying to read. But what is the client sending? There is nothing in your client code that writes.

Comment: It not meter what client trying to send.

Comment: What do you mean? Please take a little more effort to explain what should happen. You want help isn't it?

Comment: For example: I run this php socket server and it works great when I connected via Terminal(terminal ip port). When I tried to connect via Android not connected and shows me error: `socket_read() failed: reason: Connection reset by peer`. I wrote `Hello World`